# C strtok not parsing as I want

Tags: c, strtok

The `*id` value is initially `0000-0000:c29302`. Once it gets send through the `split` function its value changes to `0000-0000`. I think this has to do with it modifying the original value instead of modifying a temporary value. I want the `*id` value to stay the same. Thanks.

```
typedef struct node {
    char *id;
    char *clientid;
    char *token;
    struct node * next;
} credentials;

void split(credentials * head, char delim[]);

int main()
{
    credentials * head = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(credentials));

    head->id = strdup("0000-0000:c29302");
    head->clientid = NULL;
    head->token = NULL;
    head->next = NULL;
    split(head, ":");
    print_list(head);
}

void split(credentials * head, char *delim)
{
    char *token;
    char *temp;
    credentials * current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        temp = current->id;
        int tempNum = 0;
        token = strtok(temp, delim);
        current->clientid = token;
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            if(tempNum == 0)
            {
                current->clientid = token;
            } else {
                current->token = token;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            tempNum++;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `strtok` modifies its argument. If you don't want that, make a copy and work on that. Be sure to free it.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You have used strdup once...  If you don't want `split` to modify the argument, what is the purpose of it? It returns nothing.

Comment: @stefan.kenyon How do you do that?  Instead of `head->id = strdup("0000-0000:c29302");`, just do `head->id = "0000-0000:c29302";`.  Then down in `split()`, do `temp = strdup(current->id);`.  After verifying that works, then worry about (a) checking the return value of `strdup` in case it fails, and (b) freeing the memory allocated by `strdup()`, if/when you free this node/credentials instance.

Answer (score 3):

From `man strtok`:

> If a delimiter byte is found, it is overwritten with a null byte to terminate the current token, [...]

If you do not want your string to be modified you need to either write your own string-tokenizing function or to work with a copy of your string.

---

Note that if you do continue to use `strtok` (with a copy of your string), remember that the tokens returned by `strtok` are not new strings. They are pointers to points within the string you're working with. That means that when you free that string, all the tokens get freed at the same time.

Comment: Using `strcspn()` or `strpbrk()` instead of `strtok()` — all C90 standard functions — allows you to find where (and what!) the delimiter is.  The only gotcha is that you need to skip leading delimiters (`strspn()` does that, so using `strspn()` and `strcspn()` is often sensible).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead of **strtok**.

```
void strsplit(const char* str, const char d, char** into)
{
    if(str != NULL && into != NULL)
    {
        int n = 0;
        int c = 0;
        for(int i = 0; str[c] != '\0'; i++,c++)
        {
            into[n][i] = str[c];
            if(str[c] == d)
            {
                into[n][i] = '\0';
                i = -1;
                ++n;
            }
        }
    }
}
```